# Conditional v-if is working only for the first time?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js

I have this in my view:

```
<div class="already_voted" v-if="already_voted" >
    <p>You already voted or your are not allowed to vote</p>
  </div>
```

This is my method :

```
 upvote: function(com_id) {

              var comment_id = {
                comment_id :com_id
              }
              this.$http.post('/blog/article/comment/upvote', comment_id).then(function(response){
                upvote_total= response.data.upvote_value;
                  this.already_voted = response.data.already_voted;
                  this.$dispatch('child-msg', this.already_voted);
                $('.upvote_class_' + com_id ).text(upvote_total);
                $('.isDisabledUpvote_' + com_id).addClass('disabled');
                 $('.isDisabledDownvote_' + com_id).removeClass('disabled');
              },function(response){

              });

          },
```

Im getting value on click and if its true it need to show this div.
Problem is that this div is showed only for first time when `already_voted` is true and thats it. Next time when its true nothing happend. Any suggestion?

Comment: try creating a variable to store the vue `this` (var self = this) before the http request and then use `self.already_voted`

Comment: Ok i will try now

Comment: i have same problem when i create variable before http request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are mixing `jQuery` and `Vue`, which should be avoided unless you have a specific reason to do so. Instead you should bind attributes to data. As a basic version of what you are doing you could bind both the disabled attribute and the message to a `voted` flag:

**Markup**

```
<div id="app">
  <div v-if="voted">
    You have already voted!
  </div>
  <button v-bind:disabled="voted" @click="vote()">
  Vote
  </button>
    <button v-bind:disabled="!voted" @click="removeVote()">
  Un-Vote
  </button>
</div>
```

**View Model**

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    vote(){
      this.voted = true;
    },
    removeVote(){
      this.voted = false;
    }
  },
  data: {
    voted: false
  }
});
```

Here I'm simply binding the `disabled` attribute using `v-bind` to the `voted` flag to disabled the buttons and am using `v-if` to show a message if the `voted` flag is true.

Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/05sbjqLL/

Also be aware that `this` inside an anonymous function refers to the anonymous function itself, so either assign `this` to something (`var self = this`) outside the function or use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) if using `ES6`.

**EDIT**

I've updated the JSFiddle to show you how you might handle your situation based on you comments:

https://jsfiddle.net/umkvps5g/

Firstly, I've created a `directive` that will allow you to initiate your variable from your cookie:

```
Vue.directive('init', {
  bind: function(el, binding, vnode) {
    vnode.context[binding.arg] = binding.value;
  }
})
```

This can now be used as:

```
<div v-init:voted="{{ $request->cookie('voted') }}"></div>
```

I simply `disabled` the button to show you how to bind attributes to data, there's loads more that can be done, for example showing the message after a user clicks the button, I've just added a click counter and bound the`v-if` to that instead, so the message doesn't show until a user clicks the button:

```
<div v-if="vote_attempts">
  You have already voted!
</div>
```

Then in `vote()` method:

```
vote() {
    this.voted = true;
    this.vote_attempts++;
  },
```

Then data:

```
  data: {
    voted: false,
    vote_attempts: 0
  }
```

Comment: im using cookie to check if user votes or not, if im using v-bind then when he refresh page he will vote again.

Comment: what i have is to show message when ever he hits button vote, not to disable it

Comment: just one more thing...how can i hide that message after n seconds, and then if user hit again vote to display it??

Comment: I had a feeling you were going to ask that, you can simply use a timeout to set `vote_attempts` back to 0, you could probably just do it a boolean flag instead if you're not bothered about the number of attempts, here's the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/umkvps5g/1/

Comment: thats it...tnx a lot :)

Comment: this is important to note. "Also be aware that this inside an anonymous function refers to the anonymous function itself" +1 for this.