# Vue.js v-if only working for the first time

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

In my component template I'm using AutoDeltaSettings Component which I want to show only If `showAuto` data attribute's of the component is true.

```
<auto-delta-settings   v-if="showAuto"> </auto-delta-settings>
```

Here is the showAuto data attribute

```
data () {
    return {
      stepWidth: STEP_WIDTH,
      headerHeight: HEADER_HEIGHT,
      paddingTop: PADDING_TOP,
      paddingBottom: PADDING_BOTTOM,
      footerHeight: FOOTER_HEIGHT,
      showAuto: false
    }
  }
```

I have registered the events on the created hook

```
created () {
    EventBus.$on('protocol-changed', this.protocolChanged)
    EventBus.$on('show-advanced-settings', this.showAdvancedSettings)
  }
```

When show-advanced-settings event is emitted I'm calling showAdvancedSettings method of the component

```
methods: {
    showAdvancedSettings (toShow) {
      console.log("To Show - Before"+ this.showAuto)
      this.showAuto = toShow
      console.log("To Show - After"+ this.showAuto)
    }
}
```

I'm emitting the event from another component on a click of a button

```
showAdvancedSettingsModal () {
       console.log('Inside advanced settings opener - Before '+ this.showAdvancedSettings)
       this.showAdvancedSettings = true
       console.log('Inside advanced settings opener - After '+ this.showAdvancedSettings)
       EventBus.$emit('show-advanced-settings', this.showAdvancedSettings)
    },
```

But this only works when I click the button first time, in this case `AutoDeltaSettings` component shows up (which is a basically a modal), when I close the modal and click the button again to display the `AutoDeltaSettings` component it doesn't work.

I have read this post [Conditional v-if is working only for the first time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41592860/conditional-v-if-is-working-only-for-the-first-time)

Comment: on close modal, be sure to reset both `showAuto` and `showAdvancedSettings` to false

Comment: thanks @sovalina reseting showAuto and showAdvancedSettings back to false on closing the modal worked.